# "No module named 'sympy'" Error. Problem occurs after installation

Tags: python, module, pip, pycharm, sympy

[image]I am new to Python.
I am trying to use the Sympy package.
I am running Python 3.11 in Pycharm
I am using Windows 10.

It displays:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'

I ran  `pip install sympy`, it installed it. And when I try reinstalling it, it displays:

> Requirement already satisfied: sympy in c:\users\jrk\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (1.11.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in c:\users\jrk\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from sympy) (1.2.1)

I tried going through this guide
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-sympy
but it did not work.

I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it
both with pip and mpip
it unfortunately didnt work

at the top you can see which interpreter i am using

I can see that there is a file called sympy in my downloads folder, maybe that has to be relocated, but where to?

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: Check your PyCharm settings: which Python interpreter does it use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I do not know why it worked. But i moved the project from the local file on my computer to the server we use in our company, and then it worked

Answer (score 0):

My instructions might be a bit rusty as I don't regularly use Windows for Python but here goes:

You'll notice that the path to your Pycharm Python interpreter (c:\Users\jrk\PycharmProjects..) is different than the path reported by pip in your error messages (c:\Users\jrk\appdata..).

It's perfectly normal to have multiple versions of Python around, but you'll need to be a bit careful about which one you're invoking.

It's unclear from your description where exactly you are running the pip commands, but usually if you open built-in terminal in Pycharm, it most likely has the right virtual environment activated automatically. The command line prompt should begin with `(venv)` if that is the case. If you then run `pip install sympy` you ought to have it installed in the correct place.

If you're using a regular command prompt, you can also manually activate the virtual environment by running the  `activate` or `activate.bat` file that you'll find in `c:\Users\jrk\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\` folder.

Might want to also read a bit about virtual envs @ https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am running the pip command in the local terminal in pycharm
PS C:\Users\jrk\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>
When running the command in displays

PS C:\Users\jrk\PycharmProjects\pythonProject> pip install sympy
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in c:\users\jrk\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (1.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in c:\users\jrk\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from sympy) (1.2.1)

I dont know if this gave any clarification

Comment: Looks like the venv is not activated, hmm. Could you verify that the "Activate virtualenv" setting is enabled as described here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004289920/comments/360000638900 - it's also possible the virtualenv is broken for example due to renaming project folder. In that case it's easiest to just recreate a new virtualenv in project settings.